# SignalR: hubs vs groups

Tags: signalr

In my project I supposed to develop **a generic** publish/subscribe infrastructure, which might be used by different products (different teams) in my organization. Each product might have different methods / objects passed used for client/server communication.

I looking into SignalR, which appears to fit nicely my requirements, and I not sure  which approach is more correct:

- a. Prepare single hub per organization, where each product will be a 
  group.
- b. Prepare kind of "base hub", and each product will derive to
  its own hub.

Pros / Cons, from your experience? (from perspective of performance, scale, separation of concerns, maintainability, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It's stated with [SignalR .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server) that "There is no performance difference for multiple Hubs compared to defining all Hub functionality in a single class."

I have not seen a similar statement in regard to SignalR CORE but it could mean the same for that as well.

There is no reason that you cannot reuse methods within a single hub since you can pass parameters to them if needed and return data to the specific client that called the hub. So, keeping things generic should not be a problem.